# Gradle issue in inherit properties

Tags: gradle

I have a spring project build by gradle. I upgraded gradle from `1.7` to `2.13`

Project Structure

```
Project
     ├─ modules
     │   └───apps
     │         ├─service-engine
     │         │        └──build.gradle
     │         └─ build.gradle         
     └─ build.gradle
```

`settings.gradle` file

```
include 'modules:apps:service-engine',
```

Root build script

```
def prepareWar(war, project) {
//do somthing here
}
```

build script in `apps` module

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'war'
}
```

build script in `service-engine`

```
project.ext.set('moduleName', 'Service-Engine')

prepareWar(war, project)
```

But it gives error

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project >':modules:apps:service-engine'.
>     Could not find property 'war' on project ':modules:apps:service-engine'.

It works fine with gradle 1.7, I could not find the reason for this error.
Please anybody can help me?

Comment: It works fine when I added " apply plugin: 'war' " to build script in service-engine

Answer (score 0):

Adding build.gradle file in `modules` and add `subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'war'}` to build script work for me.